# Can't approve PayPal subscription using smart buttons or subscriptions REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to integrate PayPal subscriptions using Smart Buttons in JavaScript with sandbox app & account.

```
    paypal.Buttons(
    {
        style: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            size: 'small',
            color: 'gold',
            label: 'paypal',
            height: 35,
            tagline: 'true'
        },
        createSubscription: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.subscription.create({
                'plan_id': 'P-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
        }
    }
    ).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

After new window opens up I login with my sandbox bussiness account. The spinner appears and after a while I get a message "Something went wrong". I checked webhook and subscription is successfully created, but when PayPal navigates to checkout to approve it, the above happens.

I tried to use Subscriptions API and I made a call using Postman to create subscription. Then in response I recieved url to approve subscription. I opened it, logged in, this time I had to choose PayPal or Credit/Debit Card and again, spinner, some time passes and message appears saying "Something went wrong."

I checked wether encryption settings are disabled, cause I found it might cause issues, but it was disabled by deafult.

I also tried passing the whole subscription object from docs, not just "plan_id", but it changed nothing.

Don't have any other ideas what might went wrong. I hope someone stumbled upon this issue, found the solution and is willing to share it :D

Comment: There have been multiple versions "billing plan" objects, and the previous ones aren't compatible with the current Subscriptions API. So double-check that you're doing everything according to the latest docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ .  If you are, the next thing I would try is creating a new simple product and simple plan and seeing if those work better for you. Post the logs of those creations here if you still need help.

Comment: I created new product and plan using examples in basic integration. Created subscription for the product and tried to approve, but again, nothing.

`{"id":"PROD-4R5778526B9907156","name":"Video Streaming Service","description":"Video streaming service","create_time":"2020-02-05T21:40:28Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products/PROD-4R5778526B9907156","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products/PROD-4R5778526B9907156","rel":"edit","method":"PATCH"}]}`

Comment: Plan:
`{"id":"P-5NA7831162412634DLY5TNTI","product_id":"PROD-4R5778526B9907156","name":"Basic Plan","status":"ACTIVE","description":"Basic plan","create_time":"2020-02-05T21:42:37Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-5NA7831162412634DLY5TNTI","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-5NA7831162412634DLY5TNTI","rel":"edit","method":"PATCH"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/P-5NA7831162412634DLY5TNTI/deactivate","rel":"self","method":"POST"}]}`

Comment: Subscription: 
`{
    "status": "APPROVAL_PENDING",
    "id": "I-FMV7YPD9TTA9",
    "create_time": "2020-02-05T21:45:00Z",
    "links": []
}`

Comment: If you need the url with token to approve subscription let me know and I'll send it to you to verify.